Inject class instance in a viewmodel using by koin inject()
I have a strange error in my code which might be a limitation by koin but I don't find any information on that so I am asking here.
This is my viewmodel:
class LoginViewModel:
    BaseViewModel<LoginViewModelContract.State, LoginViewModelContract.Event>() {

    private val authProvider: AuthProvider by inject()
    ...
}

BaseViewModel is a simple class that implements androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel.
The issue here is that inject() can not be imported by koin. Does anybody know why? My setup of koin is correct, I can inject instances in all my other classes but not in this viewmodel.
Intellij shows the following error message:

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable
because of receiver type mismatch: public inline fun 
ComponentCallbacks. inject(qualifier: Qualifier? = ..., mode:
LazyThreadSafetyMode = ..., noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition?
/* = (() → ParametersHolder)? */ = ...): Lazy<TypeVariable(T)> defined
in org. koin. android. ext. android


the LoginViewModel needs to implement the KoinComponent interface
class LoginViewModel:
BaseViewModel<LoginViewModelContract.State, LoginViewModelContract.Event>(),KoinComponent


Thank you Mohamed, that was the information I was looking for.
